# Would I change my characteristics on my character sheet after picking a home world in Rogue Trader?

Tags: character-creation, rogue-trader, character-sheets

I am wondering because lets say I rolled the Stats:

- 34 WS
- 41 BS
- 38 S
- 33 T
- 40 Ag
- 30 Int
- 34 Per
- 40 WP
- and 36 Fel

If I picked the Hive World as my starting world I would get -5 T and +5 Fel, would I change my character sheet so the T field would be 28 and my Fel field to 41 on my character sheet or would I keep a note some where that it is -5 T and +5 Fel?

Answer (score 11):

You would change the base stats.  Homeworld adjustments are not advances purchased with XP.